# Define a custom variable pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a problem similar to this one:

There is an input vector of the form `(n1, n2)`, and I want a model where `f(n1, n2) = f(n2, n1)`. I want this model to be linear. For instance a `2x2` matrix that I want to learn. The `2x2` matrix has 4 weights which the training will try to learn. However, the constriction allows a clever reduction of the problem. 
`f(nvec) = W*nvec`, being `nvec=(n1, n2)`.
So, let `X = [[0, 1],[1, 0]]` be a `2x2` matrix that flips vectors, then `f(n2,n1) = W*X*(n1, n2) = f(n1, n2) = W (n1, n2)`.

Basically, the equality implies that `W*X = W`, or if `W = [[w1, w2], [w3, w4]]`, then the equality implies `W = [[w1, w1], [w3, w3]]`, i.e. the matrix has only 2 free parameters. How can I define a model like this one in pytorch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a special structure to your parameters, and you do not want to use the default parameters stored by the default layers, you can define a layer on your own and use [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#parameters) to store your parameters.

For example,

```py
class CustomLayer(nn.Module):  # layer must be derived from nn.Module class
  def __init__(self):  # you can have arguments here...
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
    self.params = nn.Parameter(data=torch.rand((2, 1), dtype=torch.float), requires_grad=True)

  def forward(self, x):
    w = self.params.repeat(1, 2)  # create a 2x2 matrix from the two parameters
    y = torch.bmm(x, w)
    return y
```